# Initializing properties in PHP

Tags: php

While I'm led to believe its likely just a design choice, is there any advantage to initializing properties in PHP to an explicit `null`?

As a force of habit I find myself doing:

```
// ...
protected $_foo = null;
protected $_bar = null;
protected $_baz = null;
// ...
```

Of course, under circumstances where *actual* data is intended to be present at object instantiation, there is purpose:

```
// ...
protected $_array = array('a', 'b', 'c');
protected $_boolean = true;
// ...
```

Is omission of a `null` initialization value *completely* functionally equivalent to inclusion of a `null` initialization? Are there any other caveats? Also, unless a property is type-checked before any assignments would be made, initialization to an empty array seems like similar situation (*and I find myself doing that constantly*)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes,

```
protected $_foo = null;
protected $_foo;
```

are completely equivalents.
As for me great choise is

- initialize clearly by `null`, if it will `null` by default
- don't initialize, if it will be overriden in constructor

It helps you to see default values quickly, helps code be self-documenting

Don't initialize array by `array()` seems to be bad idea because you can't use some function (ex. `array_push`, `array_map`)

Comment: Thanks @RiaD - This is why I had initially started initializing values to `null`, or more importantly `array()`; however, I've begun using PHPDoc comments thoroughly in my projects which (*save for the circumstances where a value is type-checked before use*) makes it largely pointless. I like your initialization choices; I'll put that into practice.

Comment: anyway I think it's better to check assigment value, than read that read something like "defaults to null". I understand that you anyway will read it but my subconscious understand `= null` faster

Comment: Regarding your point to *avoid* initializing properties to `array()`; what is the disadvantage? You mention you cannot use some functions, however I would think its more prohibitive to omit an `array()` initialization if you're going to be performing operations on the property before a value has been applied.

Comment: @Tomcat: if I always should override this array I prefer to omit initialization. But if empty array is correct default value for me, I initialize it(ex. class Validator{ private $error=array();//functions that can push something to $errors} )

Comment: That's what I figured, I just didn't want to misunderstand. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

PHP 7.4 introduced a new feature called "[typed properties](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.new-features.php)" which adds the existing PHP type system to class properties. This means that you can now enforce which types a property has without having to encapsulate it in an object.

Typed properties are a very useful feature, however, typed properties without a default value have a new state: `uninitialized`. And if they're accessed before being initialised, you'll run into a `Typed property must not be accessed before initialization` error.

So the correct answer to OPs question if you're using PHP 7.4+ is yes, it does matter whether or not you explicitly initialise your class variables and the following two lines are not equivalent any more:

```
protected int $_foo = null;
protected int $_foo; // The default value in PHP 7.4+ is now uninitialized, not NULL
```

Further reading (no relation): https://madewithlove.com/typed-property-must-not-be-accessed-before-initialization/

Comment: Thank you for finding and answering this question! Indeed much has changed in 11 years, and gladly so. Since the question was asked in the 5.4 days and isn’t concerned with typed properties, I’m leaving the selected answer as such, but this definitely deserves upvotes for visibility.

Answer (score 3):

> is omission of a null initialization value completely functionally
>   equivalent to inclusion of a null initialization?

yes

> initialization to an empty array seems like similar situation

no. You can try `foreach ($this->arr)` (or something else) and that variable should be initialized with array to avoid notice.

Comment: Thanks @OZ_ - That's the circumstance I neglected to mention but was aware of regarding arrays. However if through some other method of initialization, or during instantiation, the property intended to be an array is assigned an array value (*unconditionally*), it makes at that point no difference.

Answer (score 2):

Properties are implicitly initialized to `NULL`, there is no advantage to do this explicitly.

Comment: Thanks @user576875 - I didn't think so.

Answer (score 0):

No, ...

> ...it is **not necessary to initialize variables** in PHP however it is a
>   very good practice. Uninitialized variables have a **default value** of
>   their type **depending on the context** in which they are used - booleans
>   default to FALSE, integers and floats default to zero, strings (e.g.
>   used in echo()) are set as an empty string and arrays become to an
>   empty array.

But.. :

> Relying on the default value of an uninitialized variable is
>   **problematic** in the case of including one file into another which uses
>   the same variable name. It is also a major **security risk** with
>   register_globals turned on. E_NOTICE level error is issued in case of
>   working with uninitialized variables, however not in the case of
>   appending elements to the uninitialized array. isset() language
>   construct can be used to detect if a variable has been already
>   initialized.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php

Comment: Second quote is not actually for class properties, is it?

Comment: Thanks @Quasdunk - This is why I initially put this into practice, and ease of understanding when perusing code I haven't looked at in awhile. However, as I mentioned in another comment, I've begun using PHPDoc comments everywhere, er go, the readability factor is no longer important.

Comment: @RiaD - That quote is from the link, "Variables > Basics"

Comment: @Tomcat: and reasons, used in this qoute are actuulay only for usual variables, You get not E_NOTICE, you can't override in other files or by register_globals